# Substitute an interval of integers by string

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace all integers between 100 and 200 with the string `test` in my data. Here are some control cases:

```
`this is a control 150` = `this is a control test`
`this is a control 160` = `this is a control test`
`this is a control 150000` = `this is a control 150000`
```

My idea is to use regular expressions, and I have the following: `re.sub("\d", "test", "this is a control 150")`

However, this substitutes all integers by `test`. Is there a way to limit it to only substituting 100-200?

Answer (score -1):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = ["this is a control 150", "this is a control 160", "this is a control 160.05", "this is a control 150000"]
for i in s:
    m = re.search("\d+\.?\d*", i)
    if m:
        if 100 < float(m.group()) < 200:
            print(i.replace(m.group(0), "test"))
        else:
            print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
this is a control test
this is a control test
this is a control test
this is a control 150000
```

Answer (score -1):

If your strings are that simple, you may want to consider splitting them, parsing an int, comparing, and replacing.

```
for line in your_lines:
    num = int(line.split("control ")[1])
    if num > 100 and num < 200:
         line.replace(str(num), 'test')
```